# Are Hebrew "Qoheleth" and Latin "collate" in any way related?

Tags: etymology

The two words are more similar in sound and meaning that the Latin "conferre".  Not knowing Latin I would like a brief explanation of how "collate" comes from "conferre."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is just a random etymology question based on very, very superficial similarity. Unfortunately, there are potentially a lot of such questions and there are low-quality correspondence lists circulating on the internet.

Comment: Thank you all. My question is answered. I apologize if it was to superficial for this cite. I am certainly no linguist but am trying to learn.

Comment: Feel free to do so.  My question was answered.  First time in this group so just learning. Sorry if it is to superficial I understand you reasoning now.

Comment: Hi Larry, glad we can be of help. If you find that your question answered to your satisfaction, make sure to upvote it and click the green check mark indicating that your problem is now solved. Let me know if you have further questions about that.

Answer (score 13):

It's pure coincidence. The base word is *fero, ferre* ("I bring, to bring"), but in the past tense it's *tuli* ("I brought") and the past participle is *latus* ("brought").

If the word looks a bit weird, it's because two stems merged. We have a similar word in English that that happened to: the verb 'go', which is formed from 'go' in the present tense but from 'went' in the past tense.

*Conferre* is this word with the prefix *con-* ("together") attached to it. Before certain letters, the -n- will assimilate and change into the following letter. L is one of those, so before *latus*, the *con-* changes to *col-*.

The principle parts for this word is constructed in the same way as the base:

> *confero*, *conferre*, *contuli*, ***collatus***

Note that the assimilation is a historical process, and you will also see *conlatus* represented in certain authors.

Moreover, the English *collate* is further represented by the noun *collation*, which is directly from the Latin *collatio, collationis* (or with con- in some authors). And that final -e in *collate* is typical of dropped Latin endings (compare: *iratus* -> *irate*; *marinus* -> *marine*). Whereas that final -e is missing from Hebrew borrowings (think *hanukkah*, not *hanukke*).

Meanwhile, the Hebrew *qoheleth* isn't even a verb, like *collate* is, but a noun meaning something like "one who assembles" or "one who speaks before the assembly". The root word there is QHL. If it were borrowed in English, it would have looked very similar to the actual Hebrew word, as most Hebrew borrowings are.

Comment: The latin expression "relata refero" is a good compact example: re+latus re+fero, "I tell what I've been told".

Comment: Very helpful.  I know just enough about several languages to be dangerous (i.e. ask questions that can be annoying.)  Thank you for your kind response.

Answer (score 8):

To expand a bit more on cmw's entirely correct answer: *ferō* in Latin is what's called a **suppletive verb**. It's a verb that's taken some of its forms from one root, and some of its forms from another root; these usually result from **defective verbs** (verbs that are missing some of their forms) when they're used commonly enough that those forms are needed.

English has a few of these, like how there are no past-tense forms of the root "go". But since we use the verb "go" so often, people made do with the past tense of "wend" (as in "wend your way") to fill in the gaps, and so now we say "he goes" but "she went". That's also why "be", "is", and "was" look so different from each other: they were originally different verbs!

In Latin, *ferō* "bear" had no commonly-used past-tense forms, so the past forms of *tollō* "support" were used instead: originally *tulī* and *tlātus*. Then at some point in the history of Latin, *tl* simplified to *l*, and it became *lātus*. When the prefix *con-* "together" was stuck onto this, it assimilated: *con-lātus* > *co**l**lātus* (compare how in- + legible becomes i**l**legible).

Since QHL is also a fairly well-attested Semitic root, I see no way this could have been borrowed from one language to another. It's possible one form influenced another in translation at some point—"I'm translating the Latin word *collātiō* into Hebrew, why not use the Hebrew word that sounds kind of like *collātio*"—but this isn't the same as being related. And the meanings are different enough that I wouldn't expect this sort of translation (technically called a "phono-semantic matching") to have happened except in odd edge cases where their meanings happen to align.

Comment: It doesn't sound right to say *there are no past-tense forms of "go".* "Went" is the past tense form of "go".

Comment: @TKR Rephrased: "there are no past-tense forms of the _root_ 'go'."